# How to import a class on the-fly-and Instantiate it as an object?

Tags: python, module

I know we could use exec to load a module ( from a string ) on-the-fly

e.g.

```
path  = 'A.B'
class = 'C'
exec( "from %s import %s" %(path, class) )
```

but how I could instantiate it as an object c? btw, is above the best way to load a module from a string? it does not look very safe. thanks

regards,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python<=2.6, you can use the built-in [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function:

```
m = __import__('A.B', globals(), locals(), ['C'])
C = getattr(m, 'C')
c = C()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import importlib
m = importlib.import_module('A.B')
C = getattr(m, 'C')
c = C()
```

You can get importlib from 2.7 standard library, if you're on a lower version, for some weird reason.

Comment: Nice answer.  This is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Is "Debian stable does not include Python 2.7" that weird a reason? :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Well, since it's normal for Debian to be years behind the rest of the world, 'silly' might be better adjective then.